# To check if filename has substring of a word in a list

Tags: python

I have a list of keywords and I want to go through a directory looking for filename that contain the keyword. If found, binds the matching keyword and file path to a dictionary.

```
keywords = ['mon', 'tue', 'wed']
dict = {}

directory = os.fsencode(r"my_dir")

for file in os.listdir(directory):
  filename = os.fsdecode(file)
  ext = Path(file).suffix

  if filename in keywords:
    filepath = os.path.join(directory, filename, ext)
    dict[keyword] = filepath
```

So at the end I want something like this:

```
{'mon': 'F:\mon_001.txt', 'tue': 'F:\tue_999.txt', 'wed': 'F\wed_123.txt'}
```

Now how do I find the match?

Comment: Shouldn't you have "if keywords in filename"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're making this more complicated than it needs to be:

```
import os

keywords = ['mon', 'tue', 'wed']

directory = "my_dir"

result = {}  # dict store our results

for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    for keyword in keywords:
        if keyword in filename:
            result[keyword] = os.path.join(directory, filename)
```

This doesn't handle duplicates, however. If you want to store all matching filenames just initialize `result` as `collections.defaultdict(list)` and then when setting the found keyword use: `result[keyword].append(os.path.join(directory, filename))`

Comment: Thank you, this works. There's no duplicate filename in the directory so this will be good for me.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a nice one-liner for this case, because you need to know *which* keyword matched. An explicit loop is your best bet:

```
for file in os.listdir(directory):
    filename = os.fsdecode(file)
    ext = Path(file).suffix
    for keyword in keywords:
      if keyword in filename: # this tests for substrings
        filepath = os.path.join(directory, filename, ext)
        dict[keyword] = filepath
        break
```

Comment: Yes I was thinking that maybe there would be a one line word-matching function.